# How to count number of destroyed objects in java?

Tags: java, object

This program can count total number of objects but I am unable to count
the objects destroyed. How this can be done?

```
package displayobjno;

public class DisplayObjNo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DisplayObject obj1 =new DisplayObject();
        DisplayObject obj2 =new DisplayObject();
        obj1=null; //How to count the objects being destroyed?
    }
}

class DisplayObject
{
    static int numOfObj; 
    DisplayObject()
    {
        numOfObj+=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: No objects are destroyed by this code. The garbage-collector might, if and when it runs, which isn't predictable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You simply cannot do that in Java**:

1. finalization is not guaranteed to run,
2. garbage collection is unpredictable and any assumption on GC is misleading

**Both answers are naive and are not guaranteed to work.**

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection is unpredictable and you should not base your program logic around it. This should be used only for debugging, educational purposes or, if absolutely necessary, optimizations.

You can store your DisplayObjects in a [WeakHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html).

> An entry in a WeakHashMap will automatically be removed when its key is no longer in ordinary use.

The number of elements in the map will be the number of reachable objects or those which have not been garbage collected yet.

Answer (score -2):

Add this in class:

```
public void finalize() { 
    super.finalize();
    numOfObj-=1;
}
```

However, this method will be called only when system is collecting garbage. I mean, there can be a situation which the usage of the object is end, but system do not collect them so the method will not be called.

Comment: Every finalizer must call `super.finalize()`.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?